# android - child activity for intent ones

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, google-plus

i'm trying make simple file sharing with my android app,

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    i.setType("image/jpg");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uri_file));
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(i, "Select application");
    startActivity(chooser);
```

This works great when intent activity not bringing up any other applications.
For example, sharing to google+, changing "To" circle, sending, then returning to app, causes app restart.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: sorry CommonsWare, but i don't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved that issue, problem was wrong AndroidManifest.xml configuration,
app working in landscape, system in portrait, first intent activity as expected also in landscape, child activities in portrait, orientation switch terminated my app.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your process was terminated while you were in the background. This is perfectly normal behavior. You can read about [the process lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) to learn more about when your process will come and go.